# Alguna func/class para crear instancias de clase por un char* o string en C++

Tags: string, punteros, clase, c++11, clase-anidada

es posible crear una **instancia de una clase** buscando la por un **char*** o **string** en **c++11**: ex:

```
class MyClass:basic_class{};
basic_class* m = (basic_class*)new(typer("MyClass"));
```

no sé si sea **"typer"** algo mas o menos así? no lo hay?... gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, independientemente de la reputación que pueda tener crear un objeto de acuerdo con el nombre de su tipo, una forma de hacerlo puede ser usando el patrón de diseño "Factory", con lo que podría ponerse, por ejemplo:

```
std::unique_ptr<BasicClass> m = CreateMyClass("Flora");
```

Y podría implementarse como:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct BasicClass {
    virtual void hola() = 0;
    virtual ~BasicClass() { }
};

struct Flora : public BasicClass {
    void hola() override {
        puts("Hola Flora.");
    }
};

struct Fauna : public BasicClass {
    void hola() override {
        puts("Hola Fauna.");
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<BasicClass> CreateMyClass(const char* name)
{
    if (!memcmp(name, "Flora", 5))
        return std::make_unique<Flora>();
    else if (!memcmp(name, "Fauna", 5))
        return std::make_unique<Fauna>();
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("ni Flora ni Fauna");
}


int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<BasicClass> m = CreateMyClass("Flora");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En programación se suele recurrir constantemente a los patrones de diseño. Los patrones de diseño son plantillas orientadas a la resolución de problemas recurrentes en programación:

- reducción de dependencias
- reducción del acoplamiento
- simplificación de interfaces
- gestión de recursos
- ...

Uno de estos patrones es, como ha comentado @asdasdasd, el patrón *Factoria*. Este patrón plantea la posibilidad de disponer de una interfaz unificada que permite crear objetos de diferente naturaleza.

El diseño de la factoría es un tanto libre, si bien en C++ los diseños se implementan haciendo uso de clases. Un ejemplo:

```
class Base;

template<class T>
Base* CreadorDeObjetos()
{ return new T; }

class Factoria
{
  static std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<Base*()>> m_creadores;

public:
  static Base* NuevoObjeto(std::string const& nombre)
  {
    Base* toReturn = nullptr;

    auto it = m_creadores.find(nombre);
    if( it != m_creadores.end() )
      toReturn = it->second();

    return toReturn;
  }

  template<class T>
  static void RegistrarObjeto(std::string const& nombre)
  {
    m_creadores.insert(std::make_pair(nombre,&CreadorDeObjetos<T>));
  }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<Base*()>> Factoria::m_creadores = {};

struct Base
{
  virtual void Test() = 0;

  virtual ~Base()
  { }
};

struct Derivada1 : Base
{
  void Test() override
  { std::cout << "-- Derivada1 ok\n"; }
};

struct Derivada2 : Base
{
  void Test() override
  { std::cout << "-- Derivada2 ok\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Factoria::RegistrarObjeto<Derivada1>("Derivada1");
  Factoria::RegistrarObjeto<Derivada2>("Derivada1");

  Base* a = Factoria::NuevoObjeto("Derivada1");
  if( a )
    a->Test();
  else
    std::cout << "Derivada1 no esta registrado\n";

  Base* b = Factoria::NuevoObjeto("Derivada2");
  if( b )
    b->Test();
  else
    std::cout << "Derivada2 no esta registrado\n";

  Base* c = Factoria::NuevoObjeto("d3");
  if( c )
    c->Test();
  else
    std::cout << "d3 no esta registrado\n";
}
```

Haciendo uso de macros el sistema puede dejarse un poco más limpio:

```
// Factoria de objetos
class Base;

class Factoria
{
protected:
  static std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<Base*()>> m_creadores;

public:
  static Base* NuevoObjeto(std::string const& nombre)
  {
    Base* toReturn = nullptr;

    auto it = m_creadores.find(nombre);
    if( it != m_creadores.end() )
      toReturn = it->second();

    return toReturn;
  }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<Base*()>> Factoria::m_creadores = {};

// Utilidad para registrar los objetos
template<class T>
class RegistradorObjetos : Factoria
{
  static Base* CreadorDeObjetos()
  { return new T; }

public:
  RegistradorObjetos(std::string const& nombre)
  {
    m_creadores.insert(std::make_pair(nombre,&CreadorDeObjetos));
  }
};

// Macro (opcional) para registrar los objetos
#define RegistrarNuevoObjeto(obj) \
  static RegistradorObjetos<obj> obj##_dummy(#obj)

// Clase base
struct Base
{
  virtual void Test() = 0;

  virtual ~Base()
  { }
};

// Clases a introducir en la factoria
struct Derivada1 : Base
{
  void Test() override
  { std::cout << "-- Derivada1 ok\n"; }
};

struct Derivada2 : Base
{
  void Test() override
  { std::cout << "-- Derivada1 ok\n"; }
};

// Se registran las clases
// Ya no hace falta poner el nombre convertido en cadena
// y si nos equivocamos en el nombre salta un error en tiempo de compilacion
RegistrarNuevoObjeto(Derivada1);
RegistrarNuevoObjeto(Derivada2);

int main()
{
  // Mismo codigo que en el primer ejemplo
}
```